# Model questions trying to build a module

Tags: magento, model, slideshow

I'm trying to learn how to develop modules in magento.

Currently i'm working on a slideshow module in order to have something I can setup from backend and will be displayed on selectd product category(ies).

The problem is that i'm stuck with my model.
Knowing that i've got a first table named: "bcarmard_diaporama" containing "Id" , "Title" and "description" fields.

And a second table named : "bcarmard_diaporama_images" containing "Id", "src", "alt", "title", "description", "position" and "diaporama_id" as foreign key

I'm quite lost about how to deal with this with magento model to get images and include it in my slideshow. (diaporama means slideshow in french fyi.)

At the moment I've created those files but still don't see what the next step is.

File: local/Bcarmard/Diaporama/Model/Diaporama.php

```
Bcarmard_Diaporama_Model_Diaporama extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {
    public function _construct()
    {
         parent::_construct();
         $this->_init('diaporama/diaporama');
    } 
}
```

File: local/Bcarmard/Diaporama/Model/Resource/Diaporama.php

```
class Bcarmard_Diaporama_Model_Resource_Diaporama extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('diaporama/diaporama', 'id');
    }
}
```

File: local/Bcarmard/Diaporama/Model/Resource/Diaporama/Collection.php

```
class Bcarmard_Diaporama_Model_Resource_Diaporama_Collection extends
Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('diaporama/diaporama');
    }
}
```

Part of my config.xml file placed inside `<global> </global>` and after `<blocks> </blocks>`

```
    <models>
        <diaporama>
            <class>Bcarmard_Diaporama_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>diaporama_resource</resourceModel>
        </diaporama>
        <diaporama_resource>
            <class>Bcarmard_Diaporama_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <diaporama>
                    <table>bcarmard_diaporama</table>
                </diaporama>
            </entities>
        </diaporama_resource>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <diaporama_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </diaporama_write>
        <diaporama_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </diaporama_read>
    </resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

All in your code resource spelling is wrong..

```
  ressources should be resources also need to change it  class file structure  Ressource to resource
```

Bcarmard: you can see my blog where  have explain ,who it works http://www.amitbera.com/create-an-magento-extension-with-custom-database-table/